# Which is better to use "Your Plan" or "Current Plan"? in subscribed product

Tags: subscription

Which of the two is more effective and not confusing for the subscribes.

Comment: Both descriptions indicate a currently subscribed plan. Can you elaborate on why you think confusion could occur for subscribed users?

Comment: Yeah, but the psychology behind it... how will the audience react to it, or which of the two is more direct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to know. Specific user response to either option will depend on your particular target audience. If you want to know, test it. There's no psychology behind this, other than the 'calling something yours works better', which only testing will show, as it doesn't *always* work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Abhishek Thakkar's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/115205/57088) gives good reasoning why you might prefer "*Active Plan*" or "*Current Plan*" over "*Your Plan*" (principally the problems of talking of "*Your Plan*" in help text). I'll try to provide some other points to consider, although because you give very little context in your question, these are somewhat speculative.

- **Competitive Market with "Fickle" Users**

  In the UK at least, the "energy market" (suppliers of gas and electricity) is very competitive, with suppliers constantly vying to get consumers to switch their plans. One particularly common phrase is "*Who is your **current** supplier*". If you're in such a market, using "*Current Plan*" **may** invoke thoughts of non-permanence; that both the plan *and the supplier of that plan* can be changed at will. I feel "*Active Plan*" (or "*Your Plan*" or "*My Plan*") carry fewer such connotations.

  To a lesser degree, banks and mobile-providers also try to get consumers to switch to their offerings, so the same may apply.

If you're *not* in such a cut-throat market – you are less afraid of the user switching to an alternative provider but more concerned about the particular plan of yours that they have chosen – then it depends somewhat on the nature of the plans and how easy/often it is for the user to switch between them.

- **Selecting Between Alternate Price/Benefit Plans**

  If your product offers graduated plans (e.g. "*Basic*", "*Advanced*" and "*Premium*"), where (generally) each subsequent plan costs more but offers more benefits to the user, then I'd probably favour "*Current Plan*". Typically, users will select the level that suits them best when they first sign-up and often stay on that plan for an extended period. (Reasons for changing include realising they need more features or starting with a low-cost entry point until they're happy with your service at which point they may upgrade).

  In such circumstances, I'd probably favour "*Current Plan*" over "*Active Plan*" (see next point for some reasons).
- **Selecting Between Multiple Plans/Profiles**

  One of my interpretations of "*Active Plan*" is in contrast to "*Inactive Plan(s)*". That is, where a user might have multiple plans or profiles configured at the same time, and they can switch which one is "*Active*" at any given time. If this *is* the sort of situation you are in, then "*Active Plan*" would be the ideal choice.

I realise this last connotation may be peculiar to me (coming from quite a technical background), and may not have the same effect for everyone. Which brings me to my last point:

**The Importance of A/B Testing**

All the advice you get from here (or elsewhere) can only be general in nature. You have a specific product, with specific users. The only way to *truly* work out what is best for you and your users is to carry out [A/B Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) where you present some users with one label (e.g. "*Your Plan*") and other users with another (e.g. "*Current Plan*") and see which "works best" for the greatest number (either through analysis of their on-site behaviour [how and where they click] and/or through a survey/questionnaire of their reactions).

Comment: Both information @Abhishek Thakkar and you have given are helpful... In my case, I am working on multiple plans that can be changed anytime, not the graduated plans.

Answer (score 4):

Using "Current Plan" or better yet "Active Plan" gives a clear indication on what is active. It also makes writing FAQs simpler as the voice/tone of writing is always neutral.

A friend used to go nuts writing FAQs when the sentence would phrase like "Open your My Account".

"Click on Your Account" still sounds better, but the tone of the interface is that Ownership of the system is with the developer/company, not with the user. Like Amazon says "Abhishek's Account". To correct this and make user feel at home, early stage UI used to use "My " instead of "Your ..".

"Active/Current" is better.

Comment: ok, this cleared my mind. Very nice analogy... :) Thank you.

Comment: @LyleTanciano writing your thanks is not necessary here, please just use the voting options against answers to express your appreciation.

Comment: @JonW oh, ok, I'm new... I voted but it said reputations under 15 doesn't show the votes given but recorded.

Comment: If its clear and satisfactory, you can also accept the answer, which will close the thread.